# EmbbedId null in spring boot

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to model a business paying dividends and exposing a REST API to interact with such model.

I'm using `spring-boot 2.2.0`

Here is my `Dividend` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Dividend {

    @EmbeddedId
    DividendId dividendId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Stock stock;

    public Short period;

    public Float amount;

    @OneToOne
    public Currency currency;

    public static class DividendId implements Serializable
    {
        private DividendId() {}

        public DividendId(String stockId, String payDay)
        {
            this.stockId = stockId;
            this.payDay = payDay;
        }
        public String stockId;
        public String payDay;
    }
}
```

Doing a `POST` with the following body:

```
{
  "amount": 0.6120,
  "currency": {
    "currencyId": "EUR"
  },
  "period": 2018,
  "stock": {
    "stockId": "BME:ENG"
  },
  "dividendId":  {
    "stockId": "BME:ENG",
    "payDay": "2018-12-19"
  }
}
```

`dividendId` is set to `null` and the other properties are not `null`

- Why is `dividendId` set to `null`?
- and How may I avoid repeating the `stockId` two times?

Comment: That has nothing to do with JPA. You're asking why your JSON deserializer (Jackson, presumably) doesn't deserialize one of the fields of your class. So, what is different between that field and the other ones? (I know the answer, but you should be able to find it by yourself)

Comment: Note that using public fields is a really bad idea. So is using functional properties as an ID. And even more using an ID class without proper equals and hashCode methods.

Comment: The difference is that dividendId is a static class inside dividend. -Edit- It is not public either. -End of Edit-

About the public fields and so on, I'm just doing a scratch, once that is functional, I will refactor it to have the proper getters, constructor, hashCode-equals contract and toString

Comment: @JBNizet thank you very much, indeed it was the visibility of the field. Should you post as an answer, I will gladly accept it